# Rails enum negative scope (where not)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I use `enum` for a column in my `users` table. I want to be able to find all users who are not pending. This is my current code:

```
enum approval_status: [:pending, :approved, :declined]

User.where.not(approval_status: :pending)
```

But the SQL query becomes this:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`approval_status` != NULL)
```

No matter what enum value I put in, the SQL turns it to `NULL`

How do I get ALL users, EXCEPT for a particular value of the approval_status column?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Rails 6, negative scopes are added on the enum values.

You can use it like this:

```
User.not_pending
User.not_approved
User.not_declined
```

Related [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35381)

Comment: this works, unless you use the `_prefix: true` flag on the enum.

Answer (score 6):

Rails can't handle symbols in this case. <s>However, strings work fine</s> Strings are broken too, but in a different way :

```
enum approval_status: [:pending, :approved, :declined]

User.where.not(approval_status: :pending) //breaks
User.where.not(approval_status: 'pending') //returns 0 no matter what the string is.
```

**UPDATE**

The above answer doesn't actually work. Any string returns `0` (so it seems like it works if you're seeking your first enum).

The following will actually use your enum:

```
User.where.not("user.approval_status = ?", User.approval_statuses[:pending])
```

*Note—Rails 5 will have better enum scope support.*